# Excel: How to check if a cell is empty with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Via VBA how can I check if a cell is empty from another with specific information?

For example:

> If A:A = "product special" And B:B is null Then
>
> C1 = "product special"

[image: Illustration of example]

Additionally, how can I use a `For Each` loop on the`Range` and how can I return the value in the other cell?

Answer (score 86):

You could use `IsEmpty()` function like this:

```
...
Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A10")
If IsEmpty(rRng.Value) Then ...
```

you could also use following:

```
If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString Then ...
```

Comment: Note that `If ActiveCell.Value = vbNullString` will fail in the event that the cell contain an error such as #N/A! Better to use IsEmpty(rRang)

Answer (score 23):

`IsEmpty()` would be the quickest way to check for that.

`IsNull()` would seem like a similar solution, but keep in mind Null has to be assigned to the cell; it's not inherently created in the cell.

Also, you can check the cell by:

`count()`

`counta()`

`Len(range("BCell").Value) = 0`

Answer (score 11):

[This](http://www.herber.de/mailing/vb/html/vafctisemptyx.htm) site uses the method `isEmpty()`.

Edit: content grabbed from site, before the url will going to be invalid.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Sort _
    key1:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Set currentCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Do While Not IsEmpty(currentCell)
    Set nextCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0)
    If nextCell.Value = currentCell.Value Then
        currentCell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    Set currentCell = nextCell
Loop
```

In the first step the data in the first column from Sheet1 will be sort.
In the second step, all rows with same data will be removed.