# Do Until loop gives Unknown Runtime Error in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to pull some data from a `.csv` file on a network drive into a worksheet in a macro-enabled workbook on a different network drive using a VBScript, but I'm getting the following error:

> "Unknown runtime error."

The goal is to copy all the data from the `data` worksheet in the `data` workbook to the `test1` worksheet in the `spreadsheet` workbook. Here's my code:

```
Set app1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb1 = app1.WorkBooks.Open("Q:\sample_dir\spreadsheet.xlsm")
Set ws1 = app1.ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets("test1")
Set app2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb2 = app2.WorkBooks.Open("M:\sample_dir\data.csv")
Set ws2 = app2.ActiveWorkBook.WorkSheets("data")

i = 1

Do Until ws2.cells(i,1).value = "" 'Find how many rows there are
    i = i + 1
Loop

For j = 1 to 5000 'Find how many columns there are
    If ws2.cells(1,j).value = "" Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

For k = 1 to i
    For m = 1 to j
        ws1.cells(k,m).value = ws2.cells(k,m).value
    Next
Next

app1.ActiveWorkBook.Save
wb1.Close
wb2.Close
app1.Quit
app2.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

I had originally used a `For` loop where the `Do Until` exists (and it didn't have the error), but I looked up the looping in VBScript and saw this as an opportunity to clean up and simplify the code.

EDIT: The error says as follows:

> `excel.vbs(10,1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Unknown runtime error`

**SOLUTION:**

<del>I looked into the directory that held my .vbs script and found that a copy of the `spreadsheet.xlsm` file had been saved there. I deleted that spreadsheet and ran the code again, and it worked just fine (didn't save it to the script directory and it updated the spreadsheet on the network drive).</del>

This issue came back up again and my first solution didn't actually work. I found out the cause was due to my indexing when continuing to debug. In my code, I had used `i = j = 1` to initialize the variables for the two `Do Until` loops, which apparently doesn't work here (curse you, C background!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`app2` is a reference to the Excel `Application` object, which does not have a `Cells` collection. I think you mean to use `ws2`:

```
Do Until ws2.cells(i,1).value = "" 'Find how many rows there are
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

You're making this mistake throughout your code.

Comment: While this does fix some other problems with the code, it doesn't get rid of the runtime error. Thanks!

Comment: When you step thru your code in the debugger, what line causes the error? Can you update your question with your new code?

Comment: I just added it. It is on the line that starts the `Do Until` loop.

Comment: What's in `A1` on the `data` worksheet of your `data.csv` file?

Comment: The cell contains the string "PRODUCT"

Comment: You may want to try rebooting and trying your script again. I just ran it myself and it worked fine.

Comment: Interesting. I rebooted and I'm still getting the error.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem and have updated the question to explain it.

Comment: Interesting. Wonder why that would effect your _other_ workbook (`data.csv`) that you were looping thru. I don't get it, but I'm glad you got it going!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is going to be that "" is not the same as BLANK in Excel. So you're not running until you hit a blank cell, you're running until you hit a cell which returns "" (which is often used to create a cell with a blank appearance in a formula, ie: if a condition fails, show "").

You'll want to use the IsEmpty condition, like so:
[Excel: How to check if a cell is empty with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360651/excel-how-to-check-if-a-cell-is-empty-with-vba)

Comment: An empty value will get cast to an empty string for comparison to `""`, so his code should work.

Comment: The code works using the same statement to check for blank cells (see the `For` loop). I have a hunch there's something wrong with my `Do Until` syntax.

Comment: Fair enough - redacted.